# SQL Server Query performance with and without temp table

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on performance improvements for a query and found a strange situation.

The query looks like

```sql
SELECT 
    some_columns_and_conditions,
    SUM(val_1/100) as "val_1",
    SUM(val_2/100) as "val_2",
    SUM(val_3/100) as "val_3",
    SUM(val_4/100) as "val_4",
    SUM(val_5/100) as "val_5"
FROM
    tab_1 tb1
INNER JOIN 
    tab_2 tb2 ON (tb1.col = tb2.col)  
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT few_cols 
     FROM tab_3 
     WHERE ... ) tb3 ON (tb2.id = tb3.id)  
few_more_inner_joins
WHERE
    <filterings>
GROUP BY 
    some_columns_and_conditions 
ORDER BY 
    columns
```

It works and takes around 15 minutes.

The query is working with 4 tables:

- 2 of them are small
- 1 table has 20M records, query retrieves near 10k
- recent queries has 40M records and return near 3-4M rows

The query produces around 3-4 rows.

I tried to rewrite is with temporary table. First attempt decrease running time 2 times:

```sql
drop table #tmp

select ... 
into #tmp
from ... 

select * from #tmp
```

Unfortunately, it's not acceptable for me. I need to reach similar result with query.

Can you help me with some questions:

- Why it improved performance 2 times?
- How can I reach the same with one query?

Comment: If you want performance help you really need to post your execution plan.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: And you might find https://dba.stackexchange.com a better fit for this question.

Comment: Performance has a lot less to do with how many rows you have than what indexes you have. A properly indexed large table will still usually perform well.

Comment: @DaleBurrell The question would be on topic on dba as well, but is just as much on topic here IMO.